# Create instance of type with params argument in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to create an instance of given type in PowerShell using [New-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx). The constructor of the type being instantiated is having an argument of type [string params]. For example,

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(params string[] data)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

If I try to instantiate the above type using following command:

```
$ins = New-Object Test
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: Constructor not
>   found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type.....

What is the correct way of instantiating the above type? I don't want to pass any dummy or empty string as input parameter.

The above sample code was only for demonstration purposes. The class that I am trying to instantiate is StandardKernel from Ninject library. The class definition is given below:

```
public class StandardKernel : KernelBase
{
    public StandardKernel(params INinjectModule[] modules)
      : base(modules)
    {
    }

    public StandardKernel(INinjectSettings settings, params INinjectModule[] modules)
      : base(settings, modules)
    {
    }
}
```

The following code works fine in C#:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel()
```

Comment: Your code still doesn't have a default constructor. Try adding a line `public StandardKernel() : base() {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After understanding your issue better, I don't know of a way to create the object with pure PowerShell, but you could create a C# method that will return what you want (see the `NewTest` type below).

```
$code1 = @'
public class Test
{
    public string arguments;

    public Test(params string[] data)
    {
        if(data != null) arguments = string.Join(", ", data);
    }
}
'@

$null = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code1 -OutputAssembly c:\temp\Test.dll -PassThru

$code2 = @'
public class NewTest
{
    public static Test GetTest()
    {
        return new Test();
    }
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code2  -ReferencedAssemblies c:\temp\Test.dll

[NewTest]::GetTest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the issue with the `params` keyword that @Rynant had pointed out, your class constructor expects a parameter, but you don't provide one when trying to instantiate an object.

You could instantiate the object with an empty string to deal with this:

```
$src = @"
public class Test {
    public Test(params string[] data) {
        //...
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $src
$ins = New-Object Test ''
```

or you could overload the constructor:

```
$src = @"
public class Test {
    public Test(params string[] data) {
        //...
    }
    public Test() : this("") {}
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $src
$ins = New-Object Test
```